# Identical metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

My class was deleted, due to the virus.

I am supposed to solve the following problem:

> Let $A$ be any set of positive real numbers. Construct a metric space $(X, d)$ so that the set $A$ is identical to the set of all distances of different points of the space $X$.

My solution:
\begin{align*}
X&=\left \{ 0 \right \}\cup A\\
d(x,y)&=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x=y$,}\\
\max\{x,y\} & \text{if $x\neq y$.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Is that correct? How should I continue?

Comment: Did you check wether $d$ is actually a metric on $X$?

Comment: @Christoph how should I do this?

Comment: You need to check that $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$, that $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ and the triangle inequality $d(x,y)+d(y,z) \ge d(x,z)$ has to be satisfied for all $x,y,z\in X$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what do you suggest? How should I fix it?

Comment: @Christoph for the triangle inequality I tried: x=z, x=y and y=z, is that enough?

Comment: No, it's not, you need to show it for *all* $x,y,z\in X$.

Comment: Once you fix the typo and write $d(x,y)$ instead of $d(x,x)$, it seems right, but you need to check the metric space axioms.

Comment: @Christoph what are other cases?

Comment: @Ian what cases I should check for triangle inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triangle inequality: If $x,y,z$ are all distinct the n $x \leq \max \{x,z\}\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ and $y \leq \max \{y,z\}\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$. Hence $d(x,y) =\max \{x,y\} \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$. The case when the points are not distinct is trivial.

Comment: Thanks, that is enough?

Comment: Note that $d(x,y)$ is not always equal to $\max\{x,y\}$.

Comment: @Christoph Triangle inequality trivially holds when the points are not distinct.